# Cannot connect to Cloud SQL instance

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2, google-cloud-sql

I'm using LAMP stack on Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to connect to Cloud SQL through phpmyadmin through `config.in.php` by giving server ip, login credentials. But, Unable to connect.

Please, let me know what to do to properly connect to Cloud SQL through phpMyAdmin and make it work with Apache2.

Note: I've given network authorization for Cloud SQL instance.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you can connect to Cloud SQL instance using `mysql` command line client from your Apache machine fist - it's far easier to troubleshoot.

Procedure is covered in detail in the official documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip